# How to combine two texts?

Tags: c#, text, multiline

I have a `Single line` text box and `Multiline` text box, and want to include a word into the Single line text box with the words in `Multiline` text box per line

Like this :

**Single line** text: `"Hello"(I have to use variables)<br>`

**Multiline** words:

```
<br>
1998<br>
1999<br>
2000
```

**Expected results:**

> Hello1998
>   Hello1999
>   Hello2000
>   Pls Help me

I use the below code, but it is not working just with the `Single line` text box  and I have to manipulate by both text boxes:

```
string left = string.Format(add.Text , Environment.NewLine);
        string right = string.Format(textBox1.Text, Environment.NewLine);
        string[] leftSplit = left.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        string[] rightSplit = right.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        string output = "";
        if (leftSplit.Length == rightSplit.Length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < leftSplit.Length; i++)
            {
                output += leftSplit[i] + ":" + rightSplit[i] + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        result.Text = output;
```

Could you please advise me on the right approach?

Comment: Hi KinghtM, What are the values in `leftSplit` and `rightSplit` variables

Comment: I get the code from here              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482681/combine-2-textbox-contents-with-delimiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have single line **only one word**, then no need split it into an array.

Lets consider it as a `string left = "Hello";`

and textbox1 contains multiline words i.e.

```
string right = string.Format(textBox1.Text, Environment.NewLine); // right variable contains 1998 \n 1999 \n 2000
```

Then you can try below approach

```
var concatString = right.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(x => left + x);
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine , concatString);
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HS2hnc)

Output :

```
Hello1998
Hello1999
Hello2000
```

Answer (score 0):

`TextBox.GetLineText(int)` will help you:

```
var singlelineText = singlelineTextBox.Text;
var composedLines = new List<string>();
for (var i = 0; i < multilineineTextBox.LineCount; i++)
{
  composedLines.Add(singlelineText + multilineineTextBox.GetLineText(i));
}

result.Text = string.Join(EnvironmentNewline, composedLines);
```